# How to make bokeh (.html) file lighter?

Tags: python, plot, bigdata, bokeh

I want to make a plot for 13 years data in bokeh.
When I am making a plot for each year separately everything working fine.
But I would like to plot data all together.
When I plot one file it is about 200 MB.
While plotting the whole dataset I achieve a file that is about 2.2 GB and this file I can not open it is just loading and I can not see the plot.

Can you please give me a suggestion how to make the plot maybe lighter or to deal with such big data. Thank you in advance

this is the example of the plot for 1 year:
[image]

```
p= figure(plot_width=1400, plot_height=500)
print(df.index.values)
print(df['OSCAR_25'].values)
color = ['floralwhite', 'forestgreen', 'fuchsia', 'gainsboro', 'ghostwhite', 'gold', 'goldenrod', 'gray', 'green', 'greenyellow', 'grey', 'honeydew', 'hotpink', 'indianred', 'indigo', 'ivory', 'khaki', 'lavender',]
for key, c in zip(df.keys(), color) :
    p.line(df.index.values, df[key].values, color=c, line_width=20, alpha=1)
    p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
        hours=["%d %B %Y"],
        days=["%d %B %Y"],
        months=["%d %B %Y"],
        years=["%d %B %Y"],
    )
    
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4

p.yaxis.ticker = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180]
```

Comment: You can try using Datashader to pre-render the data into a fixed-size image. Unfortunately, we haven't implemented Datashader for native Bokeh code; you'd have to first re-implement the plot using e.g. HoloViews (see http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Spikes.html for this plot type), and then call the HoloViews `rasterize` operationn as described at http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html .

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you please help me how can i implement this holoviews in my code. If y have experience with this more. I add part of code in the description

Comment: I won't be able to implement it for you, but you might find the example at https://examples.pyviz.org/iex_trading useful.